# python cleanly exiting a class loop

Tags: python

I have a python CLASS that I am unable to exit cleanly from by calling the stop method.

I have a small delay in a loop so that I can catch the stop request as soon as possible:

```
from time import sleep
more imports...

class XXX:
    def __init__():
        self.enable = True
        more code...

    def stop(self):
      self.enable = False

    def loop(self):
      do something....   

    def run(self):
      while self.enable:    
        self.loop()
        for i in range(15):
          if(not self.enable):
            break
          else:
            sleep(1)
```

The loop runs fine until I call the stop() method and it crashes with:

```
NameError: name 'sleep' is not defined
```

How can I exit this cleanly ??

Comment: There is no Python builtin called `sleep()`, it's `time.sleep()` (and don't forget to `import time`)

Comment: Incidentally, your example never calls `stop`.

Comment: Thanks, but I imported sleep from time, this is just a snippet of the code, everything works until I call stop()

Comment: Can't reproduce the error from the code provided. Assuming sleep is actually imported. I also don't believe you can call stop while an infinite loop is running.

Answer (score 1):

`sleep` belongs to the `time` module. So just add at the top:

```
from time import sleep
```

or

```
import time
```

and then call sleep:

```
time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Yeah I agree, it seems to be imported wrong, otherwise the error wouldn't be `NameError: name 'sleep' is not defined`